# Magento 2 : How to add store credits to guest customer?

Tags: magento2, store-credit, guest

Is their any way we can add store credits to guest customers  in magento 2 ?

Comment: any thoughts ??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the Magento OOTB functionality.

You will need to write a custom module for this, but the implications are complex as you would have to manage a way to identify guest users as they don't have a customer ID. it's going to be difficult to mitigate this say in the checkout process before the order is placed, as you will have to somehow point the current store credit balance.

Comment: Thankyou for your thoughts, yes i am creating one custom module for this.